# Spring Boot Jar Hell

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I ran into multiple problems when calling third-party libraries inside a Spring Boot application. It seems the root cause of the problem is Spring Boot brought in a lot of dependencies and they can collide w/ my third-party library. A concrete example is

1. Bring Boot brought in a dependency A
2. A brought in a dependency B (version 1.1)
3. My code running inside of a Spring Boot application brought in third party dependency C. Note that C and its dependencies are packaged into a jar.
4. C brought in dependency B (version 1.0)

At run-time, C failed because B (version 1.1) is loaded, not B (version 1.0). I know .NET solved the "DLL Hell" by versioning the assemblies. How do I fix this Jar Hell in Java?

Comment: Use maven to manage your dependencies. You can then force a version.

Comment: My project is using Maven. Note that I don't have a direct dependency on B (version 1.0). My direct dependency is on C, not B so I can't specify which version B is using.

Comment: ya. that is a hell. If you use Intellij idea, you can use maven dependency graph to see how many items of your jar are there and then exclude it

Comment: The hard answer is: use modules. Either OSGI bundles or if you're using Java 9 or above you can use the built-in modules support. More likely the solution is simpler though and the dependency hell can be resolved, for example by upgrading C. I would not make your question a pseudo example and replace A, B and C with the actual offending libraries.

Comment: I can upgrade C but how do I know the exact version of B that A brought in? Running "mvn dependency:tree" only shows directly dependencies brought in by Spring Boot (A is brought in by Spring Boot directly, not B).

Comment: It doesn't for me, mvn dependency:tree shows the dependency tree, with all the nested transient dependencies below it. If B doesn't show any dependencies then it is probably not declaring any dependencies to be pulled in. Can't say anything more about it since this is still all pseudo speak.

Comment: I edited the post to include the output of of mvn dependency:tree. I have the source of org.abc.hij:samplejava and it definitely has a dependency on common-loggings.common-loggings that is not shown by mvn output.